# kendo Grid dont Show data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, asp.net-core-mvc, telerik-grid

I Use Kendo Grid for show my data in mvc core as this in **Razor View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Dates.Model.DatesIoDetails>()
                .Name("DIoDetails")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.BoxNumber).Width(140);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Weight).Width(100);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.City.Name).Width(110);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.DatesType.Name).Width(110);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.DatesZone.Name).Width(110);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Hall.Name).Width(110);
                })

                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
                .Scrollable()
                .Groupable()
                .Sortable()
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetDIoDetails", "DatesIOs", new { @area = "Software" }))
                ))
```

all of these code is in PartialView that call as

```
@Html.PartialView("MyPartialView")
```

and in controll i have this

```
  public IActionResult GetDIoDetails([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var dio = _datesIoDetailsRepository.GetAll();
        return Json(dio.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

and in _Layout i have this

```
 <environment names="Development">

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

    <script src="~/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

</environment>
```

also I add service

```
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddKendo();
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
```

I dont know why grid did not show data only show column header without data 
I set preakpoint in Code in Controller , It return Data as json when i Watch  but dont show data in Kendo Grid!
***UPDATES***
asked me about my repository, this is code in repository

```
 public IEnumerable<DatesIoDetails> GetAll() => _db.DatesIodetails
             .Include(d => d.City)
            .Include(d => d.DatesIO)
            .Include(d => d.DatesType)
            .Include(d => d.DatesZone)
            .Include(d => d.Hall)
            .Include(d => d.OutType)
            .Include(d => d.PackingType)
            .Include(d => d.Province)
            .Include(d => d.Shelf)
            .Include(d => d.Unit);
```

Comment: check if you data has `null` values.

Comment: Your grid uses the `Dates.Model.DatesIoDetails` model. After you get the data with `_datesIoDetailsRepository.GetAll()`, where are you assigning that data to your model?

Comment: I check data and data before render view return my data but don't show data in kendo Grid

Comment: I add my repository code on question,if is possible help

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?